# Assertions on many files with required pre-processing

Tags: java, spring, testing, testng, integration-testing

I have a large set of files (>1000) on which I want to be running the same set of assertions. The assertions are organized in logical groups, so I have broken them down to more than 30 `@Test` methods in a single class.

In order to run the assertions I want, I need to run before for each file some expensive pre-processing, and my assertions will run on the results of this pre-processing.

As the pre-processing is required for each `@Test` method, I want to be running executing it once for each file.

I used the `@DataProvider` the following way:

```
@ContextConfiguration({ "classpath:/META-INF/spring/ev-xml-test-context.xml" })
public class FantasticTest extends AbstractTestNGSpringContextTests {

    private String[][] FILES = new String[][] {
            { "file1.xml" },
            { "file2.xml" },
            { "..." },
            { "file1000.xml" }
    };

    private Map<String, Object> preProcessingResults = new HashMap<>();

    @BeforeClass
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        for(int i=0; i<FILES.length; i++) {
            preProcessingResults.put(FILES[i][0], expensivePreProcessing(FILES[i][0]));
        }
    }

    private Object expensivePreProcessing(String file) {
        // do something expensive
        return new ExpensiveObject(file);
    }

    @DataProvider(name = "myDataProvider")
    public String[][] dataProvider() {
        return FILES;
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "myDataProvider")
    public void test1(String filename) {
        Object preProcessingResultsForFile = preProcessingResults.get(filename);
        // assertions
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "myDataProvider")
    public void test2(String filename) {
        Object preProcessingResultsForFile = preProcessingResults.get(filename);
        // assertions
    }
    // ...
    @Test(dataProvider = "myDataProvider")
    public void test30(String filename) {
        Object preProcessingResultsForFile = preProcessingResults.get(filename);
        // assertions
    }
}
```

What I like about this approach is that in my IDE (IntelliJ) and in CI (Jenkins) I can see exactly where something failed. For example, I will see that the method `test3("file823.xml")` failed.

What I don't like about it is that:

- The pre-processing results are held in memory for all files until the assertions begin
- I have to wait until all the preprocessing is ran until I can see any assertions taking place (I would prefer if for each file the pre-processing took place and then the assertions, and then move to the next file).

I also tried the approach with the `@Factory` as described in [this DZone article](http://java.dzone.com/articles/testng-run-tests-sequentially). What I liked about it is that each instance constructed in the `@Factory` can be self-contained, executing the pre-processing of its file in its `@BeforeClass` method.

What I didn't like was that:

- I no longer had the name of the failing file in the failing test method. So all I could see was that the method `test29()` failed. This is because the `dataProvider=` attribute is now on the `@Factory`, and not the `@Test` methods.
- I still haven't managed to make the part regarding the order of the test execution work (with `testng.xml`).

I was wondering if you have any suggestion to approach this so that failing tests are self-explanatory (like in the first approach) but also pre-processing and assertions are evenly spread (like the second approach).